# Updating dependency version that doesn't change anything in your package

Tags: version-control, composer-php, versioning, semantic-versioning

Say you have a package `Foo` that relies on package `Bar`.

Initially `Foo v1.0.0` relied on `Bar v1.0.0`.

`Bar` updated to `v2.0.0`.

You now update the dependencies of `Foo` so it now requires `Bar v2.0.0`.

Since this upgrade of `Bar` does not break, add, or fix any feature in `Foo`, which part in the semantic versioning of `Foo` should you update to reflect this change?

---

Note: In case you're wondering why do I even have to update `Bar` to `v2.0.0` if it won't change anything in `Foo` -- if other packages in your app also require `Bar` but at `v2.0.0`, it will conflict if `Foo` only requires `Bar` at `1.0.0`. AFAIK this is the behavior in PHP Composer.

Comment: Why not require `Bar` using `^1.0`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry I what I meant was `Bar` requires a breaking change `2.0.0`. Updated the details for clarity.

Comment: If `Foo` is able to work with both v1 and v2 of `Bar`, you can depend on both using `^1.0|^2.0`  - that's how Symfony structures their requirements

Comment: @NicoHaase I didn't know about pipes, will try that. So if I set `Foo` to use `^1.0|^2.0`, same question applies I guess, what will be the semver of `Foo` now?

Comment: Does this issue a breaking change for `Foo` or not? If not, there is no need to issue a new major version from my point of view. I don't think there is a globally true answer to that question

Comment: @NicoHaase It doesn't change anything but if I don't set a new version, the "updated" package with pipes versioning will never be downloaded via composer right?

Comment: Unless any other package **explicitly** requires that new verion of `Bar`, it is not downloaded

Comment: This question has been [asked many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemver%5D+transitive+dependency).  One of them is probably an effective duplicate...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should a package major version change mean a sub-package major version change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247866/should-a-package-major-version-change-mean-a-sub-package-major-version-change)

Comment: @yivi nothing, I upvoted your comment in the other answer btw.

Comment: Ok I upvoted now. I didn't downvote that previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your package is a meta-package built to provide the package `Foo`, technically, it wouldn't require a change of version.

If you declare your dependency using [version ranges](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range) (because from the point of view of your package you can depend on any version irrespectively), so it becomes:

```
"foo/foo": "^1.0 || ^2.0"
```

The public API of you package hasn't changed at all. Or at least it shouldn't. The internals of your package are not the business of your package consumers, if you are correctly encapsulating your dependencies.

You are not adding or changing features, you are not breaking backwards compatibility. At most it's a patch to redeclare your dependencies, nothing more.

I'd be fine bumping `Foo` to `1.0.1`, to make the change in dependency declaration explicit, but nothing else. (Also, users of `1.0.0` and users of `1.0.1` would be effectively installing different libraries; so not changing the version number at all would be misleading, IMO; and not changing the version wouldn't allow package consumers to get the version with update `Bar`, if they needed it).

Still, it's a matter subject to a fair degree of opinion. You may want to read [this lengthy discussion](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/148), for example.

Comment: Thanx! What if the change happens in **dev** dependencies of `Foo` (e.g., a linter, a formatter, a testing library, ...)? Not sure if bumping `Foo` to `1.0.1` is a good idea in this case.